# Is my code in C portable and endianness independent?

Tags: c, embedded, portability

I want to write in C a small module, with them I could send and receive CAN frames. My target is to write a code, which is 100% portable, endianness-free and compiler independence.

Following a small example from my code.
Please write me if I am wrong, and if you have a better suggestion.

```
int CAN_FRAME[8] = {1,5,8,15,50,56,78,12};
/* RX Defines */
#define __CONVERT_TO_16BIT(HI_B,LOW_B) (( HI_B << 8  ) | (LOW_B & 0x00FF))
#define __SIG1_MASK 0b00110000
#define __SIG2_MASK 0b00000011
#define __SIG3_MASK 0b00011011
#define __GET_CAN_SIGNAL(POINTER,OFFSET,MASK) ((*(POINTER+OFFSET))&(MASK))
#define GET_LOW_BYTE(VALUE) (unsigned char)(VALUE & 0xFF)
#define GET_HIGH_BYTE(VALUE) (unsigned char)(VALUE >> 8)

/* TX Defines*/
#define PACK_SIGNAL_IN_BYTE(BYTE,VALUE,POS,BITMASK) *BYTE |= (unsigned char) ((VALUE << POS)&(BITMASK))

int main(void)
{

/* RX Simulation*/
int *p = (int*) &CAN_FRAME;
int signal1 = __GET_CAN_SIGNAL(p,4,__SIG1_MASK);
int signal2 =  __GET_CAN_SIGNAL(p,6,__SIG2_MASK);
int signal3 = __CONVERT_TO_16BIT(__GET_CAN_SIGNAL(p,7,__SIG3_MASK),__GET_CAN_SIGNAL(p,6,__SIG3_MASK));

/* Test hi/low defines */
short num =0b0101010100000001;
unsigned char low = GET_LOW_BYTE(num);
unsigned char high = GET_LOW_BYTE(num);

/* TX Simulation. Write only one byte*/
CAN_FRAME[2] = 0;
PACK_SIGNAL_IN_BYTE((CAN_FRAME+2),1,0,0x01);
PACK_SIGNAL_IN_BYTE((CAN_FRAME+2),1,1,0x02);
/* send frame*/
return 0;
}
```

Comment: those macro definitions could use more parentheses.

Comment: Names starting with `__` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Is `0b` part of C now? Is this C11?

Comment: @melpomene Thnx, I am gonna fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If referring to POSIX signals those signal masks seem unportable as signal numbering is platform depended.

Comment: @alk and what is your suggestion ? maybe to use HEX format ?

Comment: Use the definitions from the implementation's `signal.h`.

Comment: What is this `int *p = (int*) &CAN_FRAME;`? Why not just do `int *p = CAN_FRAME;`?

Comment: Binary constants with `0b` prefixes are not in C11.  They are in C++14.  They are available in a number of C compilers — GCC, Clang specifically.  On the face of it, [MSVC 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2xf226.aspx) does not support it.  The documentation for [MSVS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/) doesn't even seem to recognize C as a language — C++, C#, F#, ... but not C.  It probably does recognize binary constants in C++.

Comment: @melpomene It's not a good idea to use a custom close reason for programming questions, since the reason shown when it's closed for a custom reason is "not about programming". If you think it belongs on Code Review, it's better to flag for moderator attention asking a moderator to migrate it. I won't do it myself though because I don't know the rules on Code Review well enough to know if it belongs there.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that would mean finding a moderator who knows the rules on Code Review well enough to know if it belongs there:(   OP should migrate the Q somewhere else, after checking out if the Q is on-topic there, and delete it here.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the missing parentheses:

```
#define GET_HIGH_BYTE(VALUE) (unsigned char)(VALUE >> 8)
```

is not clean (--> implementation defined) because `VALUE` is a (signed) `short` from your context.  In

```
#define __CONVERT_TO_16BIT(HI_B,LOW_B) (( HI_B << 8  ) | (LOW_B & 0x00FF))
```

the `HI_B << 8` might overflow which is undefined for signed types too.

`int` seems to be an improper datatype at all; I would expect CAN frames to be `uint8_t`.

The `short num` should be probably an unsigned datatype too.

I do not know why you are using macros.  I would avoid them and use `inline static` functions instead which give you more type safety (especially regarding the signed operations) and will improve readability significantly.

Comment: Yes, `uint8_t` is the proper type for CAN frames, as the payload is usually between 1 and 8 8bit values long.